# Load XML file via ajax over https

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, https

I try to load an ajax file which is stored in:

```
/folder/folder/somefile.xml
```

The script is called in index so my director structure looks like this:

- index.html
- folder

  - folder

    - somefile.xml

My site is only https and it gives me this error when i execute the function:

> The page at https://somepage.com/some/long/url was loaded over HTTPS, but displayed insecure content from https://samepage.com this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

And here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type        : "GET",
        url         : "folder/folder/somefile.xml",
        dataType    : "xml",
        success     : function(xml){
           //do some crazy stuff     
        },
        error : function(){
           alert("error");
        }
```

How can i force the script to use https? And is it possible to do this with a relative path?

### EDIT

Its very complicated to explain. But it was my fault. The customer got an cms and the cms parse the folders into their own structure. All i need was a "/" before "folder/folder/somefile.xml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... very strange cause it should work...

here is my working example:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type        : "GET",
                url         : "v1/somexml.xml",
                dataType    : "xml",
                success     : function(xml){
                    alert(xml)
                },
                error : function(){
                    alert("error");
                }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**XML**

```
<companies>
    <company name="1" imageurl="logo">
    <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
    <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
    <industry> Risk Services </industry>
    <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
    </company>

    <company name="2" imageurl="logo">
    <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
    <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
    <industry> Risk Services </industry>
    <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
    </company>

    <company name="3" imageurl="logo">
    <certification> Certified Best Employer </certification>
    <employee> 5,0000 </employee>
    <industry> Risk Services </industry>
    <html_url> http://www.google.com </html_url>
    </company>
</companies>
```

I can run it over HTTP or HTTPS... result is the same and I can get access to the XML. Any difference from your example? How do you add jQuery to the page?